# Error al compilar en HTML/PDF un archivo de R

Tags: r, rstudio

No soy capaz de exportar un archivo ***.R*** a ***HTML/PDF***, me sale este error que no sé como solucionar:

```
  |.....................                               |  40% [unnamed-chunk-1]

processing file: trabajo2.spin.Rmd

Quitting from lines 3-5 [unnamed-chunk-1] (trabajo2.spin.Rmd)
                                                                                                            
Error in `readChar()`:
! no se puede abrir la conexión
Backtrace:
 1. base::load("UNIVERSIDAD/2º CURSO (2023-2024)/1º CUATRIMESTRE/Modelización estadística de datos de alta dimensión/Trabajo/DailyDemand.RData")
 2. base::readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE)
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque entonces ***soy capaz de ejecutar mi archivo*** y evidentemente ***leer los datos que estoy cargando***, que es la primera línea del archivo.

Gracias por la ayuda